# Is reading from remote networked memory mapped file or device block faster than reading from Local 7200rpm HDDs?

Tags: latency, hard-drive, memory-access

Or rather how does remote RAM compare against local Disk access?
If the answer is "it depends", what are the conditions? 
Data access patterns, ratio of read-to-writes, distance etc.

Finally, what if the local disks are NetApp filers?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is "it depends." To find out which is true in your situation, take some measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as always a question of latency versus bandwidth.  The access time to remote memory will be on the order of microseconds for gigabit networking, 100s of nanoseconds for InfiniBand and 10 GigE compared with milliseconds for local disks (example [Seagate ST3250318AS - 4.1ms](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822148451)).  As soon as the disk has hit a contiguous block it's transfer rate will exceed gigabit networking which is why local disk is predominantly considered faster.

Answer (score 0):

In general the local HDD will be faster, as the remote connection will be limited by the network bandwidth + protocol overhead.

If "local" (they're not really local if they're on a remote netapp) are netapps, they will be generally slower than remote RAM.  Since netapps will most likely have the same network bottleneck + protocol overhead, plus file system overhead (nfs/smb), and most likely some sort of RAID overhead.